# Highlighting and average/total sales value using php, sql, html/css

Tags: php, html, css, sql, mysqli

My code so far is:

```
<body>

<table border='1' bordercolor="#000000">
    <tr>

        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Product Id</font> </a></th>
        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Product Description</font> </a></th>
        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Store</font></th>
        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Qtr</font> </a></th>
        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Amount Sold</font> </a></th>
        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Cost</font></th>
        <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Sales</font></th>

    </tr>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:private","private","","private");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if (isset($_GET["sortBy"]) )
        $orderBy = $_GET["sortBy"];
    else
        $orderBy = "productId";

    $sql = "select p.productId, p.name, ps.storeNumber, ps.qtr, ps.amountSold,
            p.cost
            from Products p
            inner join ProductSold ps
            on ps.productId = p.productId
            where storeNumber = 100;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //print_r($row);
    //echo "<hr />";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['productId'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['storeNumber'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['qtr'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['amountSold'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['cost'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $sum_total = $row['cost'] * $row['amountSold'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I need to achieve the next 2 goals:

1. Highlight the sales in green when it is greater than 4,000.
2. Create a 2nd Table displaying total sales, average sales, and the lowest sales.

|Total Sales | $$$      |
|Average Sales | $$$   |
|Lowest Sales | $$$$    |

Any help or guidance in the right direction will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your first query is

```
 if($row['cost'] * $row['amountSold']  > 4,000) {
    echo "<td style="color:green">" . $sum_total = $row['cost'] * $row['amountSold'] . "</td>";
}else{
    echo "<td>" . $sum_total = $row['cost'] * $row['amountSold'] . "</td>";
}
```

And i think solution of second one is easy you can try it as u have done it in ur code itself!

Answer (score 0):

For your first goal, your best bet is to add a class name to the `<td>` which will style it accordingly. So, in your `while` loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $sum_total = $row['cost'] * $row['amountSold'];
  $total_class = intval($sum_total) > 4000 ? "green" : "";

  // print your other columns, etc
  echo "<td class='". $total_class ."'>" . $sum_total . "</td>";
  // print end of row
}

// Needed CSS
 .green{ background: green; }
```

The second part is a bit more to it. I think you'll be best suited storing all of the `$sub_total` values in an array and do the calculations there, then print out your table as before.

```
$sales_arr = array()
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // same loop as earlier
  $sum_total = $row['cost'] * $row['amountSold'];
  $sales_arr[] = $sum_total;

  // print your other columns, etc
}

$sum_sales = array_sum( $sales_arr );
$avg_sales = array_sum( $sales_arr ) / count( $sales_arr );
$low_sales = min( $sales_arr );

// Print the second table
```